# How do I get Image Data from an Image Resource?

Tags: php, azure, upload

I'm working with the Microsoft Azure cloud and need to upload images there.  Its class upload methods putBlob() and putBlobData() require either the data itself (not the resource) or the directory string as arguments, none of which is available before the image is actually written to the Blob.

```
$fp = fopen($tmp_name, 'r');
$data = fread($fp, filesize($tmp_name));
fclose($fp);

//Setup watermark destination
$new_watermarked_image_name = "watermark.jpg";

// Create image resources
$image = imagecreatefromstring($data); 
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('images/watermark_large.png');
$copyright = imagecreatefrompng('images/copyright.png');

// Merge image resource s
$image = overlay_watermark_full_size($image, $watermark);  
$image = overlay_watermark_lower_right($image, $copyright);
imagejpeg($image, $new_watermarked_image_name, 100);

//put original image
$AzureStorageBlob->putBlob("uploads", "name", $tmp_name);
//put watermarked image
$AzureStorageBlob->putBlobData("uploads", "name", ?); // ? needs to be data
```

Comment: So you're saying you need the binary data from `imagejpeg()` but it's being written to the output buffer instead?  See [examples in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) which use `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` to store it into a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to capture the buffer with ob_start, something like:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($tmp_img);
$i = ob_get_clean();
```

$i is your image blob

Comment: When I removed the 2nd argument of imagejpeg (destination), var_dump worked.  Thank you.

Comment: That is perfectly what I was looking for, awesome dude!

Answer (score 0):

By using latest [SDK for PHP](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-php) you can do this by just passing the image stream:

```
$image_stream = fopen($tmp_name, 'r');
// Check README.md of how to create $blobRestProxy
$blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob('container_name', 'my_image', $image_stream);
```

Let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: I don't need the image stream for putBlob:

    //put original image
    $AzureStorageBlob->putBlob("uploads", "name", $tmp_name);

My problem is:
    //put watermarked image
    $AzureStorageBlob->putBlobData("uploads", "name", ?); // ? needs     to be data.

Remember, I don't have a directory for the on the fly generated watermark to use as an argument in putBlob.  So I must use putBlobData, the data of which I do not have.

Comment: I don't well understand the problem. First of all, what do you have? Image data in a variable? path to the image? stream with the image?